# Create local files with python in Django

Tags: python, django, file

I want to **create files** with the extension `.txt`, `.csv`, `.bin`, etc. so the ideal would be with `import os` I think or if there is some other better way.

But I don't want to save those in the DB they are to consult the **once** or sporadically, that is, **locally** are uploaded to the server and then it is replaced and that's it.

In a simple way, I create the files I need, upload them and replace them when I need something that will not be so common.

The **directory** for these local files would be `/app/files/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to create files using directory path, something like

```
imports
def createFile (self, my_data, nameFile):
        directory = "./my_app/folder/" + nameFile + ".txt" # PATH directory
        my_File = open (directory, "w")
        my_File.write (my_data)
        my_File.close ()
        return true
```

In itself the important thing is `import os` and write well the directory where the file will be created. **No need to modify anything else**.

In the Django documentation I saw something in the import of some classes but in my case this was enough, on the other hand now that I write this answer **from django.core.files import File** which as seen is the equivalent of `import os`

I tried to use these

```py
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
```

As I do not have time and I had problems with these, I went with the easy

PS: maybe then use `from django.core.files import File` instead of `import os` as it seems to be the same, if so I update the answer.